# Time-reversibility symmetry in classical mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, time-reversal-symmetry

Newton's laws are invariant under time reversal transformation $$ t \longrightarrow -t $$ for time-independent potentials.

But Hamilton-Jacobi equation is too an equivalent description of classical mechanics which is not invariant under this transformation because of being 1st order in time.

Where is the fallacy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hamilton -Jacobi equation:

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=-H$$

with:

$$H=\frac{\partial \mathscr L}{\partial \dot{q}}\,\frac{d q}{dt}- \mathscr L$$

you get:

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial \mathscr L}{\partial \dot{q}}\,\frac{d q}{dt}+ \mathscr L\tag 1$$

reverse time $t\mapsto -t$ we obtain for eq. (1)

$$-\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=+\frac{\partial \mathscr L(-t)}{\partial \dot{q}}\,\frac{d q}{dt}+ \mathscr L (-t)\tag 2$$

so equation (2) is equal equation (1), if $\mathscr L (-t)=\mathscr L (+t)$ this is the case in your for your question.

you get the same results for Euler- Lagrange equations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Hamiltonian is invariant under [$T$-transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry), the [Hamilton-Jacobi (HJ) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) is also invariant, since Hamilton's principal and characteristic functions change sign.